# Convergence of a solution to a Cauchy problem to its supersolution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Consider the Cauchy problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}=t-x^2\\
x(1)=1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
I have proved that its solution is defined in $[1,+\infty)$ and that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} x(t)=+\infty$. Now I should prove that \begin{equation}
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} x(t)-\sqrt{t}=0.
\end{equation}

It can be noticed that $y=\sqrt{t}$ is a supersolution so, for $t\geq 1$,  $x(t)\leq \sqrt{t}$ and that $\dot{x}(t)\geq 0 $ for $t\geq 1$ but I can't figure it out.

Comment: the solution containes the Bessel function

Comment: Does the fact that $y$ is a supersolution allow you to say something like $\underset{t \to \infty}{\lim} \dot{x} (t) - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}=0$?

Comment: At the moment I can't find a way to say that...but how should it help?